# How To normlization?

Tags: database, database-normalization

In exam I got this Question can any body explain it to me....

**Sign**(MemberID, MemberName, ActivityID, ActivityName, SessionID, CoachID, CoachName, Day, From, To)

The table Sign record the enrolment information of sports club members in sports activities.  The information recorded are the the member 
name, member id,  the activity name, the activity id,  a session id that is unique within the same activity, 
the day, start and end times of the activity session enrolled, and the id and name of the 
coach supervising the activity session.  Each session must be supervised by only one coach 
and the duration of all activity sessions is one hour.

- what is functional dependencies that covers all the non-trivial
  dependencies
- what is all candidate keys for the relation **Sign**    and choose a
  primary key
- What is the highest normal form to which the relation Signup
  conforms?  Why?
- Normalize the relation Signup to the next higher normal form. 
  Indicate to which normal  form(s) the resulting relations now
  conform? And why?

My answer was

**definition of functional dependencies (FD)**

mambId->mambName

ActivityId->ActivityName

ActivityId->SessionId, Day

ActivityId->from, to

coachId->CoachName

coachId->activityName

Coach->Session, day

couach->from,to

**candidate keys**
membId , 
activityId , 
coachId .

anmd this relation is in Dirst Normal Form

Can any Body help me to understood this problem..?

Comment: since it is homework, please tag it appropriately.

Comment: What have you got so far? What is it that you don't understand? One hint to get you started, what information would you need to be able to create all the fields.

Answer (score 0):

> ActivityId->SessionId, Day

I think this is wrong, but it's a little hard to tell from what you posted.

> The information recorded are ... the activity id, a session id that is unique within the same activity, the day, start and end times of the activity session enrolled, ...

I'd interpret that to mean an activity (like "soccer") has multiple sessions. Let's say the activity "soccer" has 12 sessions. Maybe 5 of them are on Monday, 5 are on Wednesday, and 2 are on Friday.  If that's the case, SessionId->Day, but ActivityId does not.

From that, it follows that SessionId->From, and SessionId->To.

But either you or your professor has to tell us how to interpret what you've written.  We can't really go any further without knowing this.

Comment: can you help me to tell me if my answer correct or not the prinary key here is member id right . also do you think the highest normal form it 2NF

Comment: If your professor decides it's right, he wins. But I'd be really surprised if ActivityID and CoachID were candidate keys. It's probably in 2NF; it's definitely not in 3NF.

Comment: is this fuctio dependence true    MemberID--> ActivityName

Comment: I'd be surprised if MemberID determines ActivityName.  When you're trying to determine what dependencies hold, you usually analyze representative sample data, not column names.